# Xampp wont load GUI (produces errors) when I click "Go To Application", why?

Tags: apache, xampp, linux-mint

I recently installed **Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon 4.6.7** and also updated.
I just installed **xampp 8.2.4** successfully.
I have 1 user account set to *Administrator*.

When I run xampp from the terminal, everything is fine, no errors.
I am trying to run the GUI display. When I run:

```
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

...I get the startup interface. However, when I click *Go To Application*, I get the following error:

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
```

A few things to say here... First, I AM NOT trying to run firefox as a root, XAMPP IS. Second, I switched to Chrome as my default and rebooted the system to only get the same error (As many posts on the subject suggested). Third, I would try to run as a normal user as others suggested but it seems they got nowhere with that approach. Especially when you read that [running firefox as a root is a known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1206441). FOURTH BUT NOT LEAST, there are countless of people out here trying to figure this out and it seems nobody is getting anywhere! I read dozens of posts on the matter.

My first solution was to find the directive that is given to xampp in the config files, to use firefox as the default; and switch it, but could not find it in http.config, or any of the other config files. I looked in ALL of them! Furthermore, I could not find a single bit of info on just WHERE that directive is. As I stated earlier, firefox is no longer my default browser. What is going on here???

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

EDIT: Moreover, why is xampp trying to run a browser when I am just trying to use the GUI? I do not understand why xampp needs to run a browser at that point.

Screeenshot:
[image]

Comment: What makes this all so frustrating is that I have followed all instructions carefully and having trouble running a program right out of the box: Xampp for Linux, Linux Mint for desktops, etc. Re-reading the instructions brings me to the conclusion that I have done everything properly. Xampp is running, I can open localhost in my browser. Which is nice and all, but having no GUI kind of defeats the purpose of using Linux Mint, as my needs are. Might as well run plain old linux at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I had created another post in the Apache Friends Forum [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=83259). Nobbie mentioned some well described info:

> The Xampp GUi *must* run as root, as Apache and MySQL *must* be
> started as root. On the other hand, it is a restriction of your
> distribution that the browsers *must not* run as root.
>
> That is a contradiction which cannot be solved. Xampp is only a
> distribution, Bitnami does not develop the tools (neither Apache etc.,
> nor the browsers).
>
> I dont use the Xampp GUI (there is actually no need for it, its a toy,
> nothing else), i simply start Xampp as recommended in the FAQ via
> "sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start" in a terminal (see
> https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html, Chapter "How do I start
> XAMPP?"). You may also adapt the lampp startup script to your init.d
> in order to start and stop Xampp automatically when booting / shutting
> down. You should remember that Apache and MySQL are professional tools
> for running a webserver and these do not require a fancy GUI (most
> servers even dont have a graphic interface), but an educated
> administrator instead.

Would have been nice if Bitnami pointed that out to me BEFORE I installed xampp. On that note, what is the point of the GUI for Linux Xampp if it can not run in Linux Mint? Might as well remove the GUI since nobody can run it.

Comment: On the other hand, can the Xampp GUI run on other distros of Linux? Has anyone had success?